# How do I retrieve text from a doc file php

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve text from a `doc` file using `php`. This is the code that I am using:

```
    function read_doc() {
        foreach (glob("*.doc") as $filename) {

            $file_handle = fopen($filename, "r"); //open the file
            $stream_text = @fread($file_handle, filesize($filename));
            $stream_line = explode(chr(0x0D),$stream_text);
            $output_text = "";
            foreach($stream_line as $single_line){
                $line_pos = strpos($single_line, chr(0x00));
                if(($line_pos !== FALSE) || (strlen($single_line)==0)){
                    $output_text .= "";
                }else{
                    $output_text .= $single_line." ";
                }
            }
            $output_text = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/", "", $output_text);
            echo $output_text;
        }
}
```

I get this result:

> HYPERLINK mailtoAnother@email.us Another@email.us Y, dXiJ(x(I_TS1EZBmU/xYy5g/GMGeD3Vqq8K)fw9 xrxwrTZaGy8IjbRcXI u3KGnD1NIBs RuKV.ELM2fiVvlu8zH (W uV4(Tn 7_m-UBww_8(/0hFL)7iAs),Qg20ppf DU4p MDBJlC5 2FhsFYn3E6945Z5k8Fmw-dznZxJZp/P,)KQk5qpN8KGbe Sd17   paSR 6Q

Is there some solution which would clear this up so it returns just a `string` of text from the `doc` file?

Comment: There are a number of PHP libraries intended for parsing MS Word files. Try [this one](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) or [this one](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) or one of the ones mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Doc files are hard to handle with vanilla php.

Using https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHP-Unoconv I did acomplish what you need. It will acutally detect different formats and produce you with a nice xml. Docs can be found [here](http://php-unoconv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

There are also a lot of examples on the web if you search for "unoconv" + "php"

Comment: I was looking for the same solution, what I couldn't find is how to convert exactly from doc to docx. If that's possible, later on, a DomDocument and ready to go

Comment: It's of course possible to convert doc to docx. Unoconv utilizes the power of LibreOffice :)

Comment: True, here is how (it's probably needed an extra step): http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-convert-documents-between-libreoffice-and-microsoft-office-file-formats-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

Parsing an MS Word doc is tough to do with code.

This is because MS embeds a lot of data into their format, making it look like gibberish as you echo out the parsed words/paragraphs.

I recommend you try a package library (from packagist) to help you with this [Word-Doc-Parser](https://packagist.org/packages/pirishe/word-doc-parser)

Can be easily installed via `composer` if you have it on your system.

Comment: Re "it requires composer" .... well, technically you *could* download it [from Github](https://github.com/pirishe/word-doc-parser) and install it yourself manually without Composer by copying the files to your project, but frankly, who would want to bother with that kind of thing when Composer makes installing PHP libraries so easy?

Comment: @Simba good point. There is flexibility with that. I will edit that bit of my answer.